# How to georeference old map with Lambert Conical Orthomorphic Projection

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcmap

I have an old topographic map that I need to georeference for my data, but I'm not familiar with its projection. The information it has on the map is this, but I don't have any idea how to use this information in ArcMap or QGIS.

What should I do?

[image: this]

Comment: In what part of the world is the map? Can you post the entire map?

Comment: https://proj.org/tutorials/EUREF2019/exercises/projections2.html

Comment: It's in Java, Indonesia
here is the map
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SKXxYswPpg1qxDxEaUj927G7NJ4kav-K/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Please decide which of ArcMap or QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question. If it doesn’t matter and you’re asking about a GIS principle then don’t mention either and tag it as that instead.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be related to the NEIEZ zones that are listed in the [EPSG registry](https://epsg.org), but the projection and parameters don't match. Depending on where in Indonesia the map is representing, the geographic coordinate reference system (datum) could be Makassar, Batavia, or Segara. They have different areas of use, so take a look at them in EPSG.

It looks like you'll have to define a custom projected coordinate reference system.

```
Lambert conical orthomorphic = Lambert 1SP
false easting: 550000.0 m
false northing: 400000.0 m
longitude of natural origin: 110 E
latitude of natural origin: 8 S (or is it -5? did I read that correctly? My eyesight's not the best)
scale factor at natural origin: 0.9997
```

Disclosure: I work for Esri. I am on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry.